# Tweepy posting strange character on tweet

Tags: python, string, twitter, character-encoding, tweepy

I am trying to scrape news from a website to twitter. But it is posting strange characters on twitter.

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tweepy

import requests

import logging

from config import *

from time import sleep

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

logging.basicConfig(format='[%(levelname) 5s/%(asctime)s] %(name)s: %(message)s',
                    level=logging.INFO)


headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0'}
url = "https://www.todayonchain.com"

auth = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler(
   consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret
)


api = tweepy.API(auth)

old_link = ""


while True:

    r = requests.get(url=url,headers=headers)
    logging.info("Getting website date")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")
    title = soup.find("div",class_="api_article_title_sm")
    title_text = title.text
    link_container = soup.find("div",class_="api_article_include")
    link = link_container.find("a",href=True)
    link = link["href"]
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(link,headers=headers).text,"html.parser")
    new_title = (soup.title.get_text())

    logging.info("Title: %s",new_title)
    logging.info("Checking if For New Post")
    if not link==old_link:
        logging.info("New Post Detected on Website")
        old_link=link 

        try:
            logging.info("Posting to twitter")
            api.update_status(f"""{title_text}\n{link}""")
            logging.info("Posted on twitter")
        except:
            logging.info("Failed to post on twitter")


    logging.info("Sleeping For 1 Minute")
    sleep(10)
```

[sample here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjENR.png)

Comment: Which *strange characters*? I see merely regular Latin letters in your link. Please [*do not* use images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3439404) in your [mcve].
Copy the actual text, paste it into the question, then format it as code.

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case: `print('Nasdaq’s'.encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'latin1'))` shows `Nasdaqâs`…

Comment: @JosefZ any suggestion to solve this?

Comment: `r.encoding` returns `'ISO-8859-1'` for me. Setting `r.encoding = 'utf-8'` could help?